# My app keeps crashing when I want to open the new intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app keeps crashing whenever I want to open the new intent. I don't get any errors either, it just stops.

My MainActivity:

```
package nl.mirjamvanmourik.hueemulator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
LightBulbTaskListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private final Bridge bridge = Bridge.getInstance();
private final ArrayList<LightBulb> list = new ArrayList<>();

private ListView listView;
private LightBulbAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lightBulbsList);
    adapter = new LightBulbAdapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    fetchLights();
    }

    public void fetchLights(){
    try {
        list.clear();
        URL[] url = new URL[]{
                new URL (getString(R.string.BASE_URL) + 
getString(R.string.USERNAME) + "/lights/")
        };

        LightBulbTask.getLights w = new LightBulbTask.getLights(this);
        w.execute(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error:> " + e);
    }
}

public void newLightBulb(LightBulb light){
    list.add(light);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    LightBulb light = (LightBulb) list.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
LightBulbDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("LIGHTBULB", light);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

My LightBulbDetails class:

```
package nl.mirjamvanmourik.hueemulator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by mirja on 10-6-2017.
 */

public class LightBulbDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Bridge bridge = Bridge.getInstance();
    private LightBulb light;
    private TextView label;
    private SeekBar hueSeekBar;
    private SeekBar satSeekBar;
    private SeekBar briSeekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.light_details);

        light = (LightBulb) getIntent().
                getSerializableExtra("LIGHTBULB");
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTextView);
        label.setText(light.getDescr());

        hueSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.hueSeekBar);
        hueSeekBar.setProgress(light.getHue());
        hueSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {}

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                light.setHue(hueSeekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

        satSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.satSeekBar);
        satSeekBar.setProgress(light.getSat());
        satSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {}

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                light.setSat(satSeekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

        briSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.briSeekBar);
        briSeekBar.setProgress(light.getBri());
        briSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {}

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                light.setBri(briSeekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My light_details XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="64dp"
    android:paddingRight="64dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="nl.mirjamvanmourik.hueemulator.LightBulbDetails">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hueTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hue: " />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/hueSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="65535" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/satTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Saturation: " />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/satSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="254" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/briTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brightness: " />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/briSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="254" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pas aan" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Annuleer" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I already added the activity to my Manifest.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if your app crashs, you definitely get a crash report which is very important to find the issue. Just remove the filters in your logcat (Android Monitor) and you will see.

Comment: The simples issue could be, that you haven´t registered your Activity inside the manifest.

Comment: I found the solution in the Android Monitor, totally forgot about that! Thanks :) Turned out that I needed to implement Serealizable on Bridge too

Answer (score 1):

> i think you have not using Serealizable, make sure you have
>   Implemented your LightBulb class with Serealizable like below

```
class LightBulb implements Serealizable
```

Comment: I did use it for LightBulb, but I just figured out that I needed to use it for Bridge too (LightBulb uses Bridge too). Thanks for the support!

Comment: Actually there is no structure provide By you for LightBulb and Bridge too, so that's why i have suggested only for LightBulb because i can see the reference of that class. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your light bulb class must implement Serializable

for example

```
class LightBulb implements Serealizable{
     // Your Implementation
}
```

Then you can put the LightBulb object as extra.

```
LightBulb light = (LightBulb) list.get(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LightBulbDetails.class);
intent.putExtra("LIGHTBULB", light);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you can retrieve from the LightBulbDetails like that

```
light = (LightBulb) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIGHTBULB");
```